# Translate a python script into a user defined function

Tags: python, pandas, function, faker

I have a chunk of python script that I need to functionalise to enable me automate the task.
The script below is meant to generate a column using faker library, but because I have many categorical variables that need to be mirrored into a synthetic data I needed to create a function

```
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker
from faker.providers import DynamicProvider



year =  df.loc['categories', 'year']
list_year = list(year.
                     replace("'", "").
                     replace(",", "").
                     replace("[","").
                     replace("]", "").
                     split(' ')
                    )

 year_provider = DynamicProvider(
 provider_name="year_prov",
 elements= list_year
 )

 faker.add_provider(year_provider)

 gen.col("year").generation_method = faker.year_prov
```

Below is my function:

```
    col_name = 'year'
    provider_name = "year_prov"

    def dynamic_var(dataframe, 
                    categories,
                    col_name
                   ):
  
       var = dataframe.loc[categories]
       list_var = list(var.
                       replace("'", "").
                       replace(",", "").
                       replace("[","").
                       replace("]", "").
                       split(' ')
                      )
  
       year_provider = DynamicProvider(
            provider_name = provider_name,
            elements = list_var
        )

      faker.add_provider(year_provider)
  
      gen.col(provider_name).generation_method = faker.provider_name
  
      return gen.col(col_name).generation_method
```

Then call the function

```
dynamic_var(dataframe = df, 
           categories = ('categories', 'year_ashe'),
            col_name = 'year_col'
           )
```

When I call the function it output several errors
I need help

Comment: add the errors to your question